# How can I retrieve Textbox data in ASPNET MVC from a rich text editor box formatted by CKEditor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ckeditor

What I am trying to achieve is to retrieve the data of text box which has been formatted by the CKEditor that makes it a rich text code editor.

I've tried all of the traditional form retrieval methods but none of them works.
This is the form I am trying to get the data from:

```
<div id="editorDiv" style="display:none; padding-bottom:25px">

        <form method="post" >
            <input runat="server" id="textBox" TextMode="Multiline" name="textBox">
            <script>
                CKEDITOR.replace("textBox");                 
            </script>              
            <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" runat="server" name="commentSubmit">
        </form>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

The problem was that ASP has a validation method that checks data that is input.
To get data from the  just like any other `POST` request you have to add `[System.Web.Mvc.ValidateInput(false)]` before the action that handles the `POST`.

Comment: yes but don't save HTML code directly to database encode to save decode when retrieving